# Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::routeNotificationFor does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I faced issue in Laravel 5.7

Error as follows

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::routeNotificationFor does not exist.
```

My code as follows

```
$users = User::find(1);
Notification::send($users, new UserActivity());
```

Users return value as follows

```
{"id":1, "name":"First Name", "email":"name@example.com","mobile":"9999999999","reset_password":0,"avatar":null,"created_at":"2019-04-11 10:39:08","updated_at":"2019-04-11 10:39:08","deleted_at":null}
```

This is working fine with **Auth** user as follows

```
Notification::send(Auth()->user(), new UserActivity());
```

If anyone faced the same issue ?

Comment: Have you checked what does your `$users` returns? Before you send notification try dumping the `$users` like this: `dd($users);` And make sure that it returns a `App\User` instance .

Comment: $users returns are correct

Comment: you showed a json object being returned when using `User::find(1)` is that what you get by using `dd` or you print the result by returning the user `return $users`?

Comment: It is i write  to the Log file

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved from the hint @nakov

Have to add `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` trait in User model.